# appending integers as strings to a char[] in a loop

Tags: c, char, int

Given the following example.

I encode a string by adding a secret number to the numeric representation of each character.

```
A -> 41 = 65 + secret
B -> 42 = 66 + secret
1 -> 31 = 49 + secret
2 -> 32 = 50 + secret
and so on
```

So the result will have several numbers. I can print them using

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {     
    int e = ( (int)caracter + pub ) % mod;
    printf("%d ", e);                        
}
```

But how can i add all this numbers to a string like

```
123465 123466 123449 123450
```

Thank you

Comment: Combine `sprintf` and `strcat`, or `sprintf` and `strlen`, may do what you want.

Comment: What you need to recognize is ASCII provides a single character representation for what is essentially a one-byte (two hex-digit) value. For output purposes, you may want to output a 2-digit hex-value per-character. Simply treating your encoded string as an array of *unsigned char* is convenient. (which is how crypto routines handle the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Be careful with buffer size. You can do overflow.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int e[5] = {12,34,78,33,15577};
    int n = 5;
    int len = 0;
    int i = n;
    while (i--) len += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d ", e[i]);
    char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    char* str_cur = str;
    i = n;
    while (i--) str_cur += sprintf(str_cur, "%d ", e[i]);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Returns

> 15577 33 78 34 12

Comment: Getting better, but, for sake of argument, what if two of your encoded values end up as `'c'` (2-digit `int` value) and `'d'` (3-digit `int` value). If you need to then read back your encoded string, how do you discriminate between 2 and 3 digit values? (hint: by handling each byte as a 2-digit hex value, the problem goes away...) Something worth understanding and at least addressing. See: [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: What problem? Read char by char. Put every char to buffer. If space found, decode buffer to int. Yes, hexs is better. But everything is better than encoding text with static shift.